# PhoneGap not installed in Visualstudio or in node.js

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I'm get tired I try to install phonegap and use it from Visual studio 2012 but I failed, I can't download phonegap zip file I watch videos on youtube but the website is totally changed, then I try to install node.js and open its promopt and try to run cordova build but it comes with errors. an error say that I have troubke with gradle, then I try to install it using npm install gradle but without any scuccess. 
I waana run my phonegap apps

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft says:

> In Visual Studio 2013, the Cordova tools are released as a preview
>   (CTP) version. Since Cordova tools will be released as part of Visual
>   Studio 2015, we recommend that you use Visual Studio 2015 RTM to
>   develop your application through Visual Studio Tools for Apache
>   Cordova. You can download Visual Studio from the Microsoft Download
>   Center.

The cordova tools etc started to be supported after 2013 version. I guess in the 2012 version is not found. Could you try it with a higher version?